# After installing pthread package for win32, compilation error

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, gcc

I was using MinGw (4.8.1) for compilation of c++ code.It was working fine but then i installed pthread package as i need multithreading for my project.I am facing below error:

**** Build of configuration Default for project MainWithMyMakefile ****

> make all  g++ -c -v -std=c++11 -g src/Main.cpp Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe Target: mingw32 Configured with:
>   ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32
>   --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T Thread model: win32 gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
>   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-v' '-std=c++11' '-g' '-shared-libgcc'
>   '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro' 
>   c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v
>   -iprefix c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ src/Main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase Main.cpp -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase Main -g -std=c++11 -version -o C:\Users\HARSH~1.RAN\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwQeLGD.s make: *** [Main.o]
>   Error 1

Comment: Why can't you use `std::thread` available in C++11?

Comment: @SergeyS : Last line is the error in my post.

Comment: @Steephen: I am using std::thread but i was getting error as in "thread not found under std". Hence to solve that error i tried to install pthread package.

Comment: No, your line does not have a text of the error. It simply states there was an error.

Comment: @Steephen, mingw is known to not include thread support in their compiler.

Comment: @SergeyA : I am getting mentioned log using verbose mode. Is there any other way to get more details about error?
As I see, compiler has stopped before creating object files.

Comment: @SergeyA great to know. I read a discussion a while back on that thought it may be resolved

Comment: @Steephen: MinGw (4.8.1) with c+11 does support thread.

Comment: @Steephen, it's not resolved, I and it doesn't seem it is ever going to be resolved. There has been no updates for a long time, and I am afriad, the project is dead.

Comment: @harry, remove -v, and make sure you output the command before executing it. Than you can simply copy-paste and see all the output.

Comment: @Steephen: When i ran " g++ -c -std=c++11 -g Main.cpp "on command prompt , I got the windows popup saying
 " cc1plu.exe - system error : The program can't start because zlib1.dll is missing from your computer".
What does this error means, any ideas?

Comment: fixed the error , downloaded zlib1.dll and put it in Mingw\bin.

thanks guys for your prompt help.